# IP rule table look up does not seem to work

Tags: networking, routes, ip, iptables

I have a sytem with three network interfaces. Below is the configuration that I'm trying to set up. wlan0 (its actually an WiFi AP interface) - other devices connects via this interface. net1 - interface facing internet that has to be linked to wlan0 to provide internet services to devices connected via wlan0. net0 - interface facing restricted internet access to answer queries only for requests from within this subnet.

The default interface is net0 and its gateway. The output of ip route show looks like this:

```
default via 10.228.103.241 dev net0
10.228.103.240/30 dev net0 src 10.228.103.242
```

Now I would like to system to look up table 7 for route rules for all requests to eth0 and net1. So I created ip rules as below:  EDIT AFTER RESPONSE:

```
0:      from all lookup local
255:  from 8.8.0.0/16 lookup iTbl
256:  from 192.168.225.1 lookup iTbl
257:  from 192.168.172.2 lookup iTbl
32758:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

8.8.0.0 is for nameservers. Its listed as iTbl because I have defined 7 as iTbl in /etc/iproute2/rt_tables.

ip route show for table 7 looks like this:

```
default via 192.168.172.3 dev net1
8.8.0.0/16 via 192.168.172.3 dev net1
192.168.172.0/24 dev net1  src 192.168.172.2
192.168.225.0/24 dev wlan0  src 192.168.225.1
```

And finally my iptables looks like this:

```
iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 245 packets, 49904 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    3   180 ACCEPT     all  --  wlan0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 190 packets, 19182 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

iptables -nvL -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 22 packets, 2205 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 21 packets, 2145 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 91 packets, 7782 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 90 packets, 7226 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    2   616 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      net1  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

When I connected a device to wlan0 interface and try to browse internet, tcpdump shows all the requests from wlan0 seem to go via net0, which actually has to go via net1 desirably. I read through many posts and forums. After trying different things I couldn't solve the issue. I am not able to understand where its going wrong. From the tcpdump and logically looking at it, seems like the ip rule lookup to table 7 is not working. Please help to check if any of the rules has to be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The priority of the lookup rule for main currently precedes that of iTbl. Try lowering its priority or increasing iTbl's one.

Furthermore, the rules specifying the source addresses upon which the lookup table is chosen should contain the mask, i.e. `192.168.225.1/24` and `192.168.172.2/24`.

Though, in the bottom line, if all you need is the following:

1. Allow packet forwarding and masquerading from `wlan0` to `net1`.
2. Restrict access from and to `net0`.

Then this should suffice, with no need for special ip rules or ip routes:

1. Set the default gateway to `192.168.172.3`.
2. Set the default policy of the `FORWARD` ip table chain to `DROP`, keep the special rules you defined specifically for `wlan0` & `net1` and add an additional rule for forwarding packets in the opposite direction, i.e. from `net1` into `wlan0`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I saw this problem after posting and I corrected it in the code.  Sorry forgot to update the post.  It still does not work however.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Yes, that was one of the problems.  The other is not adding the 'to rule' in ip rules.  Saw this when I check with tcpdump on the two interfaces.  I will put up the rule that worked for me as answer.

Comment: @Ashgang, those new rules are unnecessary, since suitable route entries can be specified in the main routing table. Anyway, I've specified in my answer a simple way that should achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.  The suggestion looks elegant, however what I need is, for any request that originates from the system it must go via net0 and its gateway.  So the default gateway in main table I suppose should be net0's gateway.  And all traffic from wlan0 must go via net1.  This is the reason why I'm trying to redirect wlan0 and net1 settings to a separate table.
If default gw is set to net1's gateway, and all else traffic is dropped, I believe requests originating from the system will be blocked, and only wlan0 to net1 which is specified by ip table rules will work.

Comment: @Ashgang, in such a case, just set the default policy of the `FORWARD` ip table chain to `DROP`, as in my answer, so that packets originating or destined to this system aren't affected. Such packets should be routed by the ordinary `main` routing table, according to the longest prefix match found.

Comment: That sounds good. Thanks for the suggestions.  I will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the solution.  One part was adding the subnet to the tables rather than just the ip, the suggestion provided by Yoel.  The second was to add the 'to rule' in ip rules list.  My final IP rules database looks like this:

```
0:      from all lookup local
255:    from 192.168.172.0/24 lookup iTbl
256:    from 192.168.225.0/24 lookup iTbl
257:    from 8.8.0.0/16 lookup iTbl
258:    from all to 192.168.172.0/24 lookup iTbl
259:    from all to 192.168.225.0/24 lookup iTbl
260:    from all to 8.8.0.0/16 lookup iTbl
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

May be all of this is not required, more optimization can be done possibly.  But this worked, so I take it as solution.